# Getting the most common key value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

For example,

I have

```
myList = [{'imdb' : '12345'...}, {'imdb' : '54234'....}, {'imdb' : '12345'...}...]
```

I want

```
myList = [{'imdb' : '12345'...}, {'imdb' : '12345'...}...]
```

I want to get the most common imdb key value.

Thanks.

There is one question which answers how to get the most common list item, but I want the most common key value of dictionaries in a list.
This is sort of different.

Comment: Did you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564451/how-to-get-the-most-common-value-in-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
most_common_imdb_value = Counter(d['imdb'] for d in myList).most_common(1)[0]
```

If you then need a list of those dictionaries that match the most common imdb value do:

```
[d for d in myList if d['imdb'] == most_common_imdb_value]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!
What do you call these inline for loops?

Comment: They're called list comprehensions when they are inside brackets and generator expressions otherwise.